# If Statement using Lamba expression in HTML.grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

Please see the code below, I need to evaluate an element in the column, I would like to evaluate it like this but it won't work:  `if(c=>c.EditableFlag == "Y")` but this won't evaluate, how can I figure out a value in the column?

```
<li>

    @{
        if (Model.ProductDetails.WhyBuyDescriptions.Count > 0)
        {
             Html.Grid(Model.ProductDetails.WhyBuyDescriptions).Columns(column =>
             {
                 column.Custom(@<div>
                     <a href="javascript:EditRomanceCopyClick()">
                     Edit</a> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:DeleteProductClick()">
                     Delete</a> &nbsp;
                 </div>).Named("Actions");
                 column.For(c => c.Description.Shorten())
                       .Named("Why Buy Description").Format("{0}");
             })
            .Attributes(id => "WhyBuyGrid", width => "100%")
            .Render();
        }
    }
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try placing the @ before the IF statement?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
column.For(c => c.EditableFlag == "Y" ? "Editable" : "Not Editable")
```

Not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I need to determine the value of the editable flag to know if I should display the edit and delete links.